# How to set a change password in laravel 4.2 without token

Tags: laravel-4

Tell me how can i implement change password in laravel from scratch. I am using laravel 4.2 version

- User logged in his account and can change password with fill the filled

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this function in Basecontroller.php:

```
if(/*it is not reset password*/){
    $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => 'post'));
}
```

Comment: will you please give me a full code ( "controller also")